# Setting a new relation in EmberJS without original model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So I have a model created/loaded normally:

```
        let contact = self.get('store').createRecord('contact');
```

I then get the address, which is a BelongsTo relation on the model:

```
        let address = contact.get('address');
```

the returned `address` variable is a Proxy object, which the promise resolves as either the related model or null.

The question is how can I create a new address model and assign it to the original contact object, but with only the address proxy object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new address record (and not model) and assigning it to your newly created contact, you can do the following:

```
const store = this.get('store');
const contact = store.createRecord(
    'contact',
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        address: store.createRecord('address')
    }
);
```

or if you already have an address proxy and you want to create a new one only if it results to `null`:

```
const store = this.get('store');
const contact = store.createRecord('contact', { name: 'Jack' });
my_address_proxy.then(address => {
    contact.set('address', address || store.createRecord('address'));
});
```